# Try to make PDF file with laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

when I will download the pdf, its just show 404 page and no file downloaded

**view:**

```
<a href="/report/cetak_pdf" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">CETAK PDF</a>
        <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
<?php
```

**controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Report_model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use pdf;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $menu_active=0;
        $order=Report_model::all();
        return view('backEnd.report.index',compact('menu_active','order'));
    }

    public function cetak_pdf()
    {
        $order=Report_model::all();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('backEnd.report.pdf', $order);
        return $pdf->download('report.pdf');
    }

}
```

**route:**

```
Route::resource('/report','ReportController');
Route::get('/report/cetak_pdf', 'PegawaiController@cetak_pdf');
```

I tried Googling a lot but I am really lost at this point, can someone be so kind to point a lost developer in the right direction? :) Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your route in using `PegawaiController` which probably must be `ReportController`

```
Route::get('/report/cetak_pdf', 'ReportController@cetak_pdf');
```

and change the order of the routes:

```
Route::get('/report/cetak_pdf', 'ReportController@cetak_pdf');
Route::resource('/report','ReportController');
```

Comment: already change it, but i still get 404 and no file downloaded

Comment: oh, of-course the order of the routes, check the edit